# Someone else's site with my cache

Tags: seo

A few months ago, we created a site, even managed to start gaining positions, but after a while all the positions fell, and I saw 183 new incoming links in the Google console. Found out that my site is completely shown in Google results but under a foreign domain zone, but the site does not open (it was possible to open only cached versions of the page that led to my site)
I was able to remove cached pages from the search by domain (site:example.com via https://search.google.com/search-console/remove-outdated-content) But now I see the pages of this site are present on private requests of my site, and the cache They don't seem to have either.[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your question? What do you want to achieve? Are you saying that the google index is incorrect? Are you suspecting that the other site is using your content without permission? Are you using google search console (GSC)? GSC can help you check which of your pages are indexed and which of them have issues.

Comment: In case its not obvious, please edit your question and focus on what you want to ask and then request a **Reopen***